# Ruby PStore vs Postgres

Tags: ruby, postgresql, serialization, bigdata

At the moment I am using Ruby `PStore` to save large objects (> 1GB) on disk. Unfortunately the size of the PStore seems to be limited at around 2GB and this is not sufficient for my application.

I have then started to experiment with Postgres 9.5 + PostGIS. This would allow to store more data and in addition to perform some spatial operations that I will need in the future. I am using [pg-0.18.4](https://rubygems.org/gems/pg/versions/0.18.4) on a macbook pro (16GB) with Yosemite.

To my surprise (I am not a database expert) the loss in performance is enormous. As an example:

- PStore writing on disk: 130.428481s
- DB inserts: 4280.366986s

To give you more information, this is my script to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.radiation(
  id integer NOT NULL, 
  time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, 
  surface_total_shortwave double precision, 
  person_total_shortwave double precision, 
  mean_radiant_temperature double precision, 
  cell_id integer
) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE )
```

Each row of the table represents some calculated value in a certain location on a mesh (cell_id) at a certain moment in time (time).

The `INSERT` is (in Ruby):

```
INSERT INTO radiation (
  id,
  time,
  surface_total_shortwave,
  person_total_shortwave,
  mean_radiant_temperature,
  cell_id
) VALUES (
  #{id},
  '#{time}',
   #{surface_total_shortwave},
   #{person_total_shortwave},
   #{mean_radiant_temperature},
   #{cell_id}
)
```

As per recommendations found here, all the keys, indexes, triggers, etc. are disabled. All the `INSERT` are within a single transaction.

If the query is changed so that instead of storing one row per cell_id, I store the full array (`double precision[]`), the `INSERT` time becomes comparable with PStore, but I lose the spatial capabilities (I think).

My question is. Is this normal? Can the performance be improved someway? Maybe storing binary data?

Would it make any difference to switch to C with libpq directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when coding an Indexing app, first tried with the [Moneta](https://github.com/minad/moneta) gem but this didn't work out for me.
Solved it by using SqLite which has the ability to work with databases in memory.
Here an example, it is using activerecord (no rails).

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3",:database  => "db/words.db")
unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?('words')
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    create_table :words do |word_table|
      word_table.column :word, :string
    end
  end
end
```

here one of the classes of my model

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3",:database  => ":memory:")
  has_many :occurances
  has_many :filenames, through: :occurances
end
```

The indexing part (writing) uses this technique to write thousands of words in a couple of seconds, the reading part (for a website) uses plain acces from disk.

Don't know which Ruby implementation you are using, but I managed to solve this problem on other ocasions by using MRI Ruby 2.3 64 bit (on Windows), which can use far more memory and also by using jRuby, which you can provide extra memorymanagement parameters.

Since thsi kind of apps are resource hungry and huge, performance is important, so best to combine the first solution with one of these techniques.

The suggestion of Ilya is also very good, write in bulk, that can be combined with my solutions.

In any case, rethink your algorithms, often it is not necessary to do that much writing by optimising.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. Just switching to `SQLite` (on file as I need to store the data) has increased the performances enormously. My medium term plan is to use [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/). Adding also `prepared statements` has given me an additional 50% improvement.

Comment: Writing in batches (if possible) could also benefit the speed a lot, see the answer I just wrote here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332004/processing-big-amount-of-csv-files/38332342#38332342

Could you accept the answer please ?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try two things:

1. Execute all `INSERT`s in one transaction:

   ```
   BEGIN;
   INSERT ...;
   INSERT ...;
   COMMIT;
   ```
2. [Disable synchronous commit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/wal-async-commit.html) while doing so:

   ```
   SET synchronous_commit TO OFF;
   BEGIN;
   INSERT ... ;
   INSERT ... ;
   COMMIT;
   SET synchronous_commit TO ON;
   ```

   Note that this may lead to data loss in case of power loss during the insertion.

Comment: Thanks. All the `INSERT` where already in one transaction (question updated). I have tested the `synchronous commit` and the difference is negligible.

Comment: hello Ilya, other than batches, any idea how to disable synchronous commit using activerecord ? also possible in oracle ?

Comment: I'm sorry I've never used Oracle. For ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL, there exists gem [surus](https://rubygems.org/gems/surus).